# How can we store the values resolved by a JavaScript Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I am currently learning async JavaScript, and I am confused about how to get the values retured by a promise
my code:

```
let p  = Promise.resolve("Passed")

let x = p.then(msg=>msg).catch(msg=>msg)
setTimeout(()=>console.log(x), 2)
console.log(x)
```

Output:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { 'Passed' }
```

How can I get the string "Passed" which is being returned by the `.then` function, and why the promise is pending even when the Promise is resolved? But when we `console.log` its value using a `setTimeout` function is gives its value, and How to get the `"Passed"` from `Promise { 'Passed' }`

Comment: "*the string "Passed" which is being returned by the .then function*" - no it isn't. `.then()` returns a promise. Do the `console.log` **inside** the `then` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get a response out of promise right now.
To solve you can use 2 approaches:

subscribe inside of then with a new function which gets the promise result // but it would be asynchronously like this

```
var p = Promise.resolve([1,2,3]);
p.then(function(v) {
  console.log(v[0]); // 1
});
```

second one is :
use async function with **await** structure

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // in this part it will be wait until promise will end its work

  alert(result); // "done!"
}

f();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are intended to use promises this way:

```
p.then((x) => {
    console.log(x);
});
```

or this way (only works in async functions):

```
x = await p;
```

Normally, p would actually be a function that returns a promise, like this:

```
function p() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("message");
    });
}
```